# How to draw below tooltip popup using canvas

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

How to draw below tooltip like popup using canvas and CustomPainter in Flutter. Also it have some shadow to this popup. [image]

I tried using below code but exact output is not same like above.

```
class CustomStyleArrow extends CustomPainter {
 @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final Paint paint = Paint()
   ..color = Colors.black
   ..strokeWidth = 1
   ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
  const double triangleH = 10;
  const double triangleW = 25.0;
  final double width = size.width;
  final double height = size.height;

  final Path trianglePath = Path()
   ..moveTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height)
   ..lineTo(width / 2, triangleH + height)
   ..lineTo(width / 2 + triangleW / 2, height)
   ..lineTo(width / 2 - triangleW / 2, height);
  canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, paint);
  final BorderRadius borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(4);
  final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, width, height);
  final RRect outer = borderRadius.toRRect(rect);
  canvas.drawRRect(outer, paint);
}

 @override
 bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. For rounded triangle corner you should use `Path`'s `addArc` or `relativeArcToPoint` methods.
2. To combine rectangle and triangle paths you should use `Path.combine` static method with with operation `PathOperation.union`.